# Can't Find layer-list as a Root Element in android

Tags: android

I want to use the layer list in android for setting the background.But i cannot find it in drawable .What should I do to get that?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

in the above link which tells Resource pointer to a LayerDrawable but cant find it in my eclipse. how to get this ?

Comment: Explain briefly. what you want to do?

Comment: i want to use the layer-list in android.but i can find it in drawable root element.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937182/imagebutton-from-drawable-in-layer-list) It may help you

Comment: but the problem is when i type the layer-list it will give a error because it not support the layerlist. how to correct it